# How to avoid vaue field in remix ide and send send msg.value directly from function

Tags: solidity, evm

below is my smart contract but it won't update the balance of the recipient. because I'm avoiding a value field in remix ide what i want to achieve is to set msg.value directly from my function so I don't have to put value in the value field of remix ide

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Bulksend {
    address payable recipient;

    constructor() {
        recipient = payable(msg.sender);
    }
   function send(uint256 amount)payable public{
       amount = msg. value;
     payable(recipient).transfer(amount);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible**. Contract function can't simply take ether from your wallet. The only way to send ether to a contract is by defining the value field, which you are trying to avoid.

This however only applys to the native token (ETH). This can be done using an ERC20 token like wrapper ether. You would define the amount in the input parameter and give approval to the contract. Then the contract can send the tokens within the function.